# Getting error with my json parser class

Tags: php, android, html, json, web-services

I am making an android application in which I have to use jsonparser class.
But it continuously return null json object.

One more thing json parser class is called from mainActivity with in doingbackground function of asyktask.

JSON ANSWER:

```
{"products":[

{"pid":"1","name":"sulman",

"price":"125.00","created_at":"2013-05-05 04:00:00",
"updated_at":"2013-05-07 07:21:28"}, 
"pid":"2",

"name":"faizan",

"price":"124.00",

"created_at":"2013-05-06 05:00:00",
"updated_at":"2013-05-08 04:28:04"}],"success":1}




This my json parser class
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

// catch the exception//
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//bufferreader read the input stream//
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            json = "{json_parse" + "[" + json + "]" + "}";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
```

//returning a null object//
            return jObj;

```
    }
}
```

Comment: plz show String which u are getting from server

Comment: and remove all code not related to the json problem.

Comment: did you log values/messages at different parts of your code to see if loops are entered, and values are as you expect them to be?

Comment: Yes I did. and the values are exactly the same as I expected. But json string is not parsing to json Object.

Comment: jObj = new JSONObject(json); is the line giving an exception

Comment: @user1796974 : ur json string is not valid as u have posted with question

Comment: would u like to tell me which json string i should use that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

extra `}` on your json code or need to add `{` on json code it must be this

extra `}`

```
 {"products":[
    {"pid":"1","name":"sulman",
     "price":"125.00","created_at":"2013-05-05 04:00:00",
     "updated_at":"2013-05-07 07:21:28", 
     "pid":"2",
     "name":"faizan",
     "price":"124.00",
     "created_at":"2013-05-06 05:00:00",
     "updated_at":"2013-05-08 04:28:04"}],"success":1}
```

output

```
  stdClass Object
 (
    [products] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [pid] => 2
                [name] => faizan
                [price] => 124.00
                [created_at] => 2013-05-06 05:00:00
                [updated_at] => 2013-05-08 04:28:04
            )

    )

    [success] => 1
 )
```

or need to add `{`

```
 {"products":[
    {"pid":"1","name":"sulman",
     "price":"125.00","created_at":"2013-05-05 04:00:00",
     "updated_at":"2013-05-07 07:21:28"}, 
     {"pid":"2",
     "name":"faizan",
     "price":"124.00",
     "created_at":"2013-05-06 05:00:00",
     "updated_at":"2013-05-08 04:28:04"}],"success":1}
```

output

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [products] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [pid] => 1
                [name] => sulman
                [price] => 125.00
                [created_at] => 2013-05-05 04:00:00
                [updated_at] => 2013-05-07 07:21:28
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [pid] => 2
                [name] => faizan
                [price] => 124.00
                [created_at] => 2013-05-06 05:00:00
                [updated_at] => 2013-05-08 04:28:04
            )

    )

    [success] => 1
 )
```

Comment: i mistakenly missed this { but in actuall my code is included this { on "pid :2".

Comment: if in the json missed `{` NULL return in `jObj = new JSONObject(json);`